# Deploy laravel from github to heroku gives error" In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package"

Tags: laravel, heroku

I uploaded a laravel app working fine locally on github and deployed on heroku. but I kept Getting this error when deployed on heroku. view [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfIV1.png)

I tried these cmds on heroku console

composer install

composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

but when ever I enter "php artisan ui bootstrap --auth" it says artisan not a directory or not found but its there.

I have tried "composer dump-autoload" as well, still same..

pls help

Answer (score 0):

You can't install things interactively on Heroku. At best, it will appear to work temporarily but get reverted within 24 hours. All dependencies must be declared so Heroku can install them at build time.

Run `composer require laravel/ui` *locally*, then commit your updated `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files and redeploy.